# Java run Chromedriver with selenium on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java web servlet that I want to host on an Ubuntu 18.04 server running Tomcat 8. The servlet uses selenium and chromedriver during execution. The servlet was running fine on my local machine which is running Tomcat 8 on Windows 10.
I tried to edit the code to run on my server as below:

```
static WebDriver browser;
static AutomatedPromethee automatedPromethee;
static ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.setBinary(new File("/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/chromedriver"));

//capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I managed to successfully import the selenium libraries and also copied the chromedriver file to a folder on my server. However, the webapp does not open a new browser instance as expected as per the last line of code above. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please post what error are you getting?

Comment: @KajalKundu unfortunately there's no error on the tomcat logs.

Comment: I can see you are using ‘headless’ options in that case you need to install xvfb.Could you please install xvfb using apt-get Install command and check wheather it works.

Comment: @KajalKundu I have already installed it.

Comment: If moved from Windows, clean your project first.

Comment: Update the question with the Selenium error trace logs

Comment: There's no errors in catalina log fine. Only lines showing that the servlet was deployed successfully. It runs on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trouble, I finally managed to solve this issue. Here's a chronology of the things I did, may be some weren't necessary, but who knows?

*Install xvfb and dependencies

```
apt-get install xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

*Install google chrome browser and make sure its at `/usr/bin/google-chrome` (Symlink is also ok).

*Copy chromedriver to `/usr/local/bin/`

*Make sure that chromedriver has +x (executable) permission

Then run the following commands on Ubuntu:

```
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

My final servlet code was as follows:

```
static WebDriver browser;
static ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");

options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps someone else too.